# sibling html update not working as desired jquery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to change the contents of a div which I receive from a php file. The problem I am facing is with this particular part $(this).siblings("div").html("info");
Its not updating the contents. It works fine when not in the success call back what am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){
$("button").click(function(){


var name =$(this).attr('name');
var info = 'test=' + name;
var div= name;

$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "yes.php",  
  data: info,  
  success: 

  function(data)

  {  
           $(this).siblings("div").html(data);  

        }  
    });        



  });
  });




</script>

<style type="text/css">
.max {
color: #00F;
height: 25px;
 }
 .recent {
background-color: #0F0;
width: 500px;
height: 24px;
 }

 div.min{
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #F00;
}
</style>


 <div>


 <div class="min">Whats up dude?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   </div>
  <button name='what'>Read More</button>
  </div>


    <br/>
   <div>

    <div class="min">Whats up dude?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   </div>
   <button name='jack'>Read More</button>

   </div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML markup as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside an ajax call points to the xhr object and not to `$("button")` anymore. Store it in a var, previous to the ajax call, and use it later:

`$this = $(this);`

and later:

`$this.siblings("div").html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$(this)` has the scope you're thinking it does in the callback.  Try using an explicit selector instead:

```
 $(".divClass").siblings("div").html(data);
```